# Too much space between bracket and equation ( \left{ \begin{matrix} \end{matrix} \right. )

Tags: align

In my TeX document, I use a composed function (potential pot/quantum well) and wrote it with this code:

```
\begin{align*}
    V(x) = \left\{ 
       \begin{matrix} -V_0 \Leftrightarrow -\frac{a}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{a}{2} \\ 
       \\ 
          \ \ \ \ \ \ \  0 \Leftrightarrow x \geq \frac{a}{2} \text{ und } x \leq - \frac{a}{2} 
       \end{matrix} 
       \right.
\end{align*}
```

I get this

[image]

What I want is this

[image]

I would appreciate it if someone could help me.
Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you employ an `align*` environment here?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the many `\ \ \ \ \ \ \` in your code. But I would suggest using `cases` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  V(x) = \begin{cases}
           -V_0, &  -\frac{a}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{a}{2} \\
           0,    &  x \geq \frac{a}{2} \text{ und } x \leq - \frac{a}{2}
         \end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: cases]

BTW, shouldn’t the `und` be `oder`? I don’t think you can get `x \geq \frac{a}{2}` and `x \leq - \frac{a}{2}` simultaneously (if `a>0`).

Comment: Thank you very much :)
Yes, I corrected with ´\geq´ to ´>´ and ´\leq´ to ´<´, than the ´und´ is right ;)

Comment: @astronerd You are welcome. But I was referring to `x>1 and x<-1`. You cannot have a number that is both greater than 1 *and* less than -1. In rigorous math language it should be phrased as `x>1 or x<-1`. In your case, it can be further simplified to `\text{otherwise}` ;-)

Comment: The potential V(x) is 0 for x greater a/2 and for x less -a/2.
Here is a plot I made (with python, matplotlib): https://postimg.cc/TpHNNp61

Comment: @astronerd Yes, I understand where you’re coming from. The message you’re trying to convey is that `V(x) = 0` whenever `x` is outside of `[ -a/2, a/2 ]`. What I’m saying is that the word `and` has special meaning in mathematical logic. When you write `-a/2 <= x <= a/2`, you are saying `x >= -a/2 and x <= a/2`. You cannot have `x < -a/2 and x > a/2` because this gives you two mutually exclusive statements and the result is empty. The word for this case should be `x < -a/2 or x > a/2` with the word `or`, not `and`. See, e.g., [this answer on Math.SX](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1433154).

Comment: @astronerd Perhaps your intention of using `and` was to simply *list the alternatives* as Jyrki Lahtonen commented on that post. But `and` also acts as *logical conjunction* (that is, both must be satisfied simultaneously). The former usage is fine, but it can cause ambiguity. Using `or` is perfectly fine in math literature and I’d argue it’s preferred. ;-)

Comment: I see what you mean :D Sorry for this slopiness, I'm a physics-student (we don't take mathematical logic that rigorous or serious, as long as our theories are compatible with experiments and observations) :P
But thank you!